# R: how to aggregate and separate x into multiple columns? FUN = unique

Tags: r, aggregate, unique, multiple-columns, data-cleaning

I'm aggregating a data.frame by edu (education level) and id_study and the function  I am using is "unique".

```
db1 <- aggregate (edu ~ id_study, data=steps, FUN=unique)
```

the result i get is correct, but strings (for edu) are converted to numeric elements and are all in one column. How do I rectify this?
Person with the right answer gets a tick!

Thank you everyone for reading this and help.

edit**************** Below is the data set.

S

```
structure(c("DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", 
"DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", 
"DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", 
"DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", 
"DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", "DZA_2003_STEPS", 
"DZA_2003_STEPS", "9", "7", "6", "9", "7", "6", "3", "12", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "6", "6", "3", "3", "6", "11", "7"), .Dim = c(20L, 
2L))

      [,id_study]      [edu]
 [1,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "9" 
 [2,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "7" 
 [3,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "6" 
 [4,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "9" 
 [5,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "7" 
 [6,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "6" 
 [7,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [8,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "12"
 [9,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [10,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [11,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [12,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [13,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [14,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "6" 
 [15,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "6" 
 [16,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [17,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "3" 
 [18,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "6" 
 [19,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "11"
 [20,] "DZA_2003_STEPS" "7"
```

Comment: Maybe the column `edu` is a factor, coded internally as integers. Try `as.character(edu)`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(steps)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(steps, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have updated it as requested

Answer (score 0):

I have reversed the order of the variables in the formula and it seems to do what you want.

First, some data preparation code, to give it column names and coerce to class `data.frame`.

```
colnames(steps) <- c("id_study", "edu")
steps <- as.data.frame(steps)

db2 <- aggregate (id_study ~ edu, data = steps, FUN = unique)
db2
#  edu       id_study
#1  11 DZA_2003_STEPS
#2  12 DZA_2003_STEPS
#3   3 DZA_2003_STEPS
#4   6 DZA_2003_STEPS
#5   7 DZA_2003_STEPS
#6   9 DZA_2003_STEPS
```